# Calculating BPM with inputs

Tags: code-golf

Program the shortest code that will calculate the average BPM (Beats per Minute) using 8 data points of time passed. This is my first post, and I haven't seen a question similar to this. Since I am a fan of rhythm games, it would be nice to have a small handy tool to calculate BPM using your own keyboard and your own sense of rhythm (if you have one...)

## Challenge

- All inputs must be singular. (i.e. Only pressing "enter" as "input")
- Your program must take at least 9 inputs. (To create 8 data points of time passed.)
- Your program should output the BPM of the keypresses rounded at 2 decimal points. (i.e. 178.35)
- **Timing starts at first input. Not start of program**

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins.

## Example Input and Output

Provide at least one example input and output. Make sure they match your own description of what the input should look like.

Input:

```
> [Enter-Key]
# User waits 1 second
...  7 more inputs
> [Enter-Key]
```

Output:

```
> 60
```

**Current winner is [KarlKastor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135955/72656) at 22 Bytes using Pyth**

**Even though the winner was using Pyth, the Matlab answer was a notable answer.**

Comment: Ha! Interesting, welcome to PPCG; for future reference we also have a [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?cb=1) where you can get feedback on your challenges before posting them. This is pretty well done though.

Comment: How do we compute the BPM? Do we start timing on the first keypress or when the code starts running? Do we divide by 7 or 8 before extrapolating?

Comment: Hmm.. So timing should start on the first keypress. As for division, I will change it to do 9 inputs (so you divide by 8)

Comment: Cool question! Good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 22 bytes

```
 wJ.d0 mw8.Rc480-.d0J2
```

(yes there's a leading space)

Input is 'enter' presses.

If additional output is allowed I can remove the spaces and get a score of 20 bytes.

[image: example execution]

### explanation

```
 wJ.d0 mw8.Rc480-.d0J2
 w                      # take the first input
                        # (space) throw the result away
  J.d0                  # store the current system time in J
       mw8              # take 8 inputs and throw the result away
                 -.d0J  # difference of current time and J
             c480       # divide 480 by this
           .R         2 # round to 2 decimal places
```

Answer (score 9):

## MATLAB/Octave, <s>58 56</s> 55  bytes

Thanks @LuisMendo for -1 byte!

```
input('');tic;for k=1:7;input('');end;fix(48e3/toc)/100
```

You have to press enter 9 times. (Also works in Octave.)

Here you see it in action, left MATLAB, right Octave:

[image][image]

Comment: D'oh! but is `round(.,2)` does not work, or does it in the newer versions?

Comment: Oh, it only works in Matlab

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>77</s> 74 bytes

```js
(i=8,n=Date.now,t)=>onclick=_=>(t=t||n(),i--||alert((48e6/(n()-t)|0)/100))
```

Creates an `onclick` event on the global `window` object. Send beats by clicking anywhere in the window.

### Test Snippet

```js
let f=
(i=8,n=Date.now,t)=>onclick=_=>(t=t||n(),i--||alert((48e6/(n()-t)|0)/100))

f()
document.write("Running... click anywhere here")
```

```css
*{user-select:none}
```

Comment: 632.41! quite a good calc :) +1

Answer (score 6):

## Python 3, <strike>93</strike> <strike>92</strike> 81 bytes

Saved 11 bytes thanks to [Felipe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66418/felipe-nardi-batista).

```
import time
a,*l,b=[input()or time.time()for i in' '*9]
print(round(480/(b-a),2))
```

Comment: [81 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzeVK1FHK0cnyTY6M6@gtERDM78ILKwHIjQ004DcTIXMPHUFdS3LWK6Cosy8Eo2i/NK8FA0TCwN9jSTdRE0dI03N//8B)

Comment: i tried `print('%.2f'%(480/(b-a)))` and `print(f'{480/(b-a):.2f}')` (python3.6+), but both have the same bytecount

Answer (score 5):

### **Javascript, <strike>100</strike>, <strike>84</strike> thanks to [Powelles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52433/powelles), 82 bytes thanks to [Justin Mariner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/69583/justin-mariner)**

```
z=>{(a=alert)();i=0;s=(n=Date.now)();while(i++<8)a();a((48e4/(n()-s)).toFixed(2))}
```

```js
(z=>{(a=alert)();i=0;s=(n=Date.now)();while(i++<8)a();a((48e4/(n()-s)).toFixed(2))})();
```

Comment: You should be able to use `Date.now()` instead of `new Date().getTime()` and `48e4` instead of `480000`.

Comment: Also you can alert the result back instead of returning it and assign alert to a variable like `(a=alert)()` for your first usage and then later use `a()`.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot, I'd never thought of `48e4`, and instanciate AND call `alert` together : `(a=alert)()`.

Comment: You can also switch `s` to use `Date.now()`, and drop the `.getTime()` later. And then you can alias `Date.now` to a shorter name. And the initial `z=` isn't needed since you aren't calling the function recursively. Down to [69 bytes here](https://tio.run/##FcjBDsIgDADQX@Fmm4l42GHJxJM/0rlGUFIMVEk0fjvq8b0rPameS7yrXWjhZCWv3J0za@YqGzUtl5sJXHhrNOTHJfSXP76BPCUuioBz9Pu5ehB/IuWd5PbPFmJiiMNwmJB@JhgnHh0IoK2In96/)

Comment: Oh, and your solution doesn't round to 2 decimal places like the challenge asks for.

Answer (score 5):

## Bash + common Linux utilities, 58

```bash
script -tt -c'sed -n 9q'
sed '1c2k0
s/ 2/+/;$a480r/p' t|dc
```

Answer (score 4):

## Java 1.5+, <s>345</s> <s>339</s> <s>361</s> 337 bytes

-34 bytes thanks to Michael for pointing out I forgot to fix my imports

```
import java.awt.event.*;class B{public static void main(String[]a){new java.awt.Frame(){{addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){long x=System.currentTimeMillis();int b=0;public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){if(e.getKeyChar()==' '&&b++==9){System.out.println(Math.round(6000000.0*b/(System.currentTimeMillis()-x))/100.0);}}});setVisible(1>0);}};}}
```

Listens to the user as they press the space bar. Then, when the user has pressed it 9 times, prints back to the user the current BPM:

[image]

*Image has debug messages not present in golfed code.*

---

## Ungolfed:

```
import java.awt.event.*;

class B {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        new java.awt.Frame() {
            {
                addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
                    long x = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    int b = 0;

                    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                        if (e.getKeyChar() == ' ' && b++ == 9) {
                            System.out
                                    .println(Math.round(6000000.0 * b
                                            / (System.currentTimeMillis() - x)) / 100.0);
                        }
                    }
                });
                setVisible(1 > 0);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

---

Kinda fun to try and get a highscore...

```
KEY PRESS0 AT 250ms.
KEY PRESS1 AT 343ms.
KEY PRESS2 AT 468ms.
KEY PRESS3 AT 563ms.
KEY PRESS4 AT 672ms.
KEY PRESS5 AT 781ms.
KEY PRESS6 AT 880ms.
KEY PRESS7 AT 989ms.
485
```

Comment: I made a minor change and that I wanted 9 inputs so you could have 8 data points for input instead of 7. (should just be a small change.)

Comment: Missed a space: `String[]a) {new java`

Comment: Another thing is, I put a requirement that says "It should output the BPM of the keypresses rounded at 2 decimal points." Does this round to 2 decimal places?

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx does now.

Comment: Are you sure you need awt? Wouldn't that be shorter in console?

Comment: record is `2027.03` BPM xD slightly modified the code for some better benchmarking

Comment: You can change `java.awt.Frame` to `Frame`. You've got 2 classes prefixed with `java.awt.event.` so it's less verbose to just `import java.awt.event.*;` and remove those prefixes. You can get rid of the braces around the if. You can declare `b` as a long on the same line as `x`. No idea what the six million is for but you can represent it in scientific notation as `6e6`. `100.0` can drop the last zero.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Something tells me you weren't hitting the spacebar at 33Hz (which would sound the note C0).  Does that rely on the repeat-rate of the key?  Apparently on Linux the behavior of Java's KeyListener does not handle a key held down the same way as on Windows (on Linux it is treated like multiple keypresses even without a key-up event) - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1736828/how-to-stop-repeated-keypressed-keyreleased-events-in-swing

Comment: @DarrenRinger its true that i held down the key. the repeat-rate is still default setting, yet it was not always consistent. most times i had `2020.2` BPM and only once the slightly higher value

Comment: @flawr meh, I suppose you could just put a scanner in a loop; I thought this was more interesting. `while(b!=9){new Scanner().nextLine();b++;}System.out.println([MATH SHIT]);` would work fine.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Well this is [tag:code-golf] :)

Answer (score 3):

## C# (.NET Core), <s>193</s> <s>206</s> <s>189</s> <s>186</s> <s>155</s> <s>143</s> 137 bytes

*-47 bytes thanks to [TheLethalCoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/38550/thelethalcoder)*
*-4 bytes thanks to [Nazar554](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/29636/nazar554)*
*-16 bytes thanks to [Luc](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/15738/luc)*
*-2 bytes thanks to [Kamil Drakari](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/71434/kamil-drakari)*

```cs
_=>{var x=new long[9];for(int i=0;i<9;){Console.ReadKey();x[i++]=DateTime.Now.Ticks;}return Math.Round(48e8/(x[8]-x[0]),2);}
```

Also added to byte count:

```cs
using System;
```

Whole program:

```cs
namespace System
{
    class A
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Func<int, double> f = _ =>
            {
                var x = new long[9];
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; )
                {
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    x[i++] = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
                }
                return Math.Round(48e8 / (x[8] - x[0]), 2);
            };
            Console.WriteLine(f(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be shorter to have two variables have one outside the loop after the first key press for start time and then overwrite another in the loop. I don't think you need to format the output value so just `+""` or even returning the double would be fine. `namespace System.Diagnostics{}` is probably shorter but you only use `Diagnostics` on the `w` so fully qualifying that is probably shorter too. Note that you should include `using System;` in your byte count for the `Console` call.

Comment: Using a `for` loop and initialising `i` in it is probably shorter than the `while` loop. And I think that might be it!

Comment: replace `540000.0` with `5.4e5`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder challenge rule is that the result has to be rounded to 2 decimal points, that's the reason I used string with formatting. Thank you for the tips.

Comment: @Nazar554 thank you for the tip

Comment: @GrzegorzPuławski Ah thought it said at least, can ignore that then. But `namespace System.Diagnostics{}` is shorter than the two usings.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder yes, I'm in progress of updating the code.

Comment: You can drop the trailing semi colon, change `()` to `_` (empty/unused inputs are allowed). Would using two `long`s be shorter than the array? Would using `DateTime`s be shorter than the `Stopwatch`?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder array is shorter because of the cute w.ElapsedMilliseconds that would need to be used twice in code. And DateTime comparison is quite lengthy, because you can't compare it directly, but by using TimeSpan class (from what I can tell looking at documentation). Added the tip about semicolon and ()

Comment: Well you'd do something like `(end-start).Milliseconds` and set `end` and `start` to `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder ah yes, it dropped bytes by a lot (to 155). Thank you. I also tried to somehow get rid of the array, but the lowest i managed to go with DateTime was 174, so more than with array.

Comment: Yeah probably because of the repeat calls with `DateTime` in them. Glad I could help!

Comment: I think you've got an error in your calculation. If you replace ReadKey with Thread.Sleep(100), you should get a bit less than 600 BPM, but your code gives more than that (around 670 BPM). The formula should be "60sec * 1000ms / (deltaMs / 8points)" which translates to  "48e8 / deltaMs". Also, you can return$"{48e8/(d[8]-d[0]).Ticks:n2}" fo -20 ;-)

Comment: @Luc Hmm I did it for 9 points so maybe that's the reason. Will fix it, thanks!

Comment: @Luc neither my compiler nor TIO seem to work with the $"" format so I will stay put about it untill I can check it later on my main computer with newer VS. But thank you for the changes anyway!

Comment: @GrzegorzPuławski, oh, right... .NET Core :-) Haven't really played with it yet.

Comment: I think you should be able to save some bytes by doing `8/TimeSpan.TotalMinutes` instead of `54e4/TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds`. Also, by a quick check using 'Math.Round(value,2)' instead of `value.ToString("n2")` seemed to save a few characters, partially because it needed fewer parentheses

Comment: @KamilDrakari It was already changed to Ticks instead of TotalMilliseconds. But thanks or the Math.Round tip!

Answer (score 2):

## Python + curses, 122 bytes

```
import curses as C,time as T
s=C.initscr()
C.cbreak()
t=0
exec's.getch();t=t or T.time()'*9
print'%.2f'%(540/(T.time()-t))
```

Requires the `curses` module to be loaded.

-9 bytes thanks to Felipe Nardi Batista

Comment: What's the curses module do? Curse you?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Of course that's certainly what it does.

Comment: time() needs to start at first input and not at program execution.

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx fixed; thanks

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Jokes aside, it's a terminal-based GUI library.

Comment: i didn't test it, but `import curses as C,time as T` should save a byte, and i think you could do: `exec's.getch();t=t or time();'*9` to save even more bytes

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### C++, 150 bytes

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
#define G getchar()
void f(){G;auto s=clock();G;G;G;G;G;G;G;G;std::cout<<round(6000/(double(clock()-s)/8000))/100;}
```

Comment: You could save 5 bytes if you remove the `#define` and instead do `void f(){for(int i=0,auto s=clock();i++<9;){getchar();}std::cout<<round(6000/(double(clock()-s)/8000))/100;}`

Comment: No, because if i do that, timing will start before the first input, while it's said **Timing starts at first input. Not start of program**

Comment: Would it be possible to change line 3 to `#define G;getchar()` and then changing `clock();G` to `clock()G`?

Comment: @Zacharý I get syntax errors

Comment: For some reason, my compiler complains about `round`.

Comment: @Zacharý I almost forgot your comment here. What compiler do you use ? Since i tested with Visual C++, my compiler doesn't complain as long as i include iostream header.

Comment: I used the one on https://repl.it

Answer (score 2):

### vba, 57

```
msgbox"":x=timer:for i=1to 8:msgbox"":next:?480/(timer-x)
```

press enter, or click on the OK in the message box.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 74 bytes

```python
from timeit import*;print('%.2f'%(480/timeit('input()',input(),number=8)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1ehJDM3NbNEITO3IL@oRMu6oCgzr0RDXVXPKE1dVcPEwkAfokBDPTOvoLREQ1NdB8rQySvNTUotsrXQ1NT8/58LBgA)

This will give you silly numbers in TIO since it runs all the inputs at once but it does work.  `timeit()` returns the execution time of the statement `'input()'` in seconds excluding the setup parameter `input()`.
[TIO with a 1s delay](https://tio.run/##NYo7CoAwEAV7T5FGsivivxCClxEiLphkiWvh6SP@XjUzPD5lDb5PiRyHKErI2WyJwT1Eot5eGI7kBXRedYvOYRib@j2AJs@HAJrbq32zlqFFXX659IebbZxGREwp@3cB) per input for validation.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>180</s> 135 bytes

*-45 bytes thanks to @SocraticPhoenix suggesting to use `System.in` directly.*

```java
x->{System.in.read();long t=System.nanoTime(),i=0;for(;i++<8;System.in.read());System.out.printf("%.2f",4.8e11/(System.nanoTime()-t));}
```

An anonymous lambda function with an unused argument that must be assigned to a functional interface method that throws an `Exception` (example below). Reads from console; beats are sent by pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

### Ungolfed w/ Surrounding Test Code

```java
public class A {
    interface F{void f(Object x) throws Exception;}

    public static void main(String[]a) throws Exception {
        F f =

        x->{
            System.in.read();
            long t=System.nanoTime(),i=0;
            for(;i++<8;System.in.read());
            System.out.printf("%.2f",4.8e11/(System.nanoTime()-t));
        }

        ;
        f.f(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be shorter to just read directly from `System.in`?

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix I've never actually tried that, but it seems to work; just using `System.in.read()` to block until input is received. Thanks! Will update answer.

Comment: 25559105.43 bpm with [this](https://tio.run/##ZU9NS8NAEL3nVwwFYUOb1YqHQow3exMP9SYetslunbiZDbuTGin57TEtwdj2XYaZ98WUaq8SV2sqi6@@z60KAV4UEhwiGIDE2huVa1gf9g4LMOJ1W@qcoY2BP737DvDc5rpmdJR20clUN1uLOQRWPIyTrRoixYY90u79Q11bx7oj1mAgi/7WNnmauCM2P4F1JZGk16oQcXrGWkc74GwUkSL3hpUW8QKzu3OlcV6kOJ8/rtLLyIvMkXYNy3r4gI2Y3ch7M1s8yJVeLm/FVVvC/zO66ZvpaKQR1Fg76rqo6/tf) lol

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>79</s> 84 bytes

```
scan();s=Sys.time;x=s();replicate(8,scan());cat(round(60/as.numeric((s()-x)/8),d=2))
```

Only works when using enter, since that will end scan immediately. Explicitly uses `print` for its `digits` argument, handling the rounding.

```
> scan();s=Sys.time;x=s();replicate(8,scan());cat(round(60/as.numeric((s()-x)/8),d=2))
1: 
Read 0 items
numeric(0)
1: 
Read 0 items
1: 
Read 0 items
1: 
Read 0 items
1: 
Read 0 items
1: 
Read 0 items
1: 
Read 0 items
1: 
Read 0 items
1: 
Read 0 items
[[1]]
numeric(0)

[[2]]
numeric(0)

[[3]]
numeric(0)

[[4]]
numeric(0)

[[5]]
numeric(0)

[[6]]
numeric(0)

[[7]]
numeric(0)

[[8]]
numeric(0)

[1] 439.47
```

Comment: Does this also round correct with a CPM greater than 1000?

Comment: @RomanGräf woops, nope. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 117 bytes

There's already a [C# (.NET Core) answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135496/15738) that this one builds on. Added interpolated string (that .NET Core seems to lack) for output and shaved some bytes by using long array instead of DateTime.

```
_=>{var d=new long[9];for(var i=0;i<9;){Console.ReadKey();d[i++]=DateTime.Now.Ticks;}return$"{48e8/(d[8]-d[0]):n2}";}
```

### Humane version

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Func<int, string> f = _ =>
        {
            var d = new long[9];
            for (var i = 0; i < 9;)
            {
                Console.ReadKey();   // Switch these two to "automate" key presses.
                //Thread.Sleep(100); 

                d[i++] = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
            }
            return $"{48e8 / (d[8] - d[0]):n2}";
        };

        var result = f(1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 58 bytes

```
gets;t=Time.now;8.times{gets};p (480/(Time.now-t)).round 2
```